# How to properly do GIT pull in SH?

Tags: bash, git, sh

I need to create script which will do pull request. Currently my code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
cd "/var/www/project" 

GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /var/www/deploy/access-key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'

git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

The thing is that each time I get:

> Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'. Failed to add the RSA host
>   key for IP address '104.192.143.1' to the list of known hosts
>   (/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts). git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied
>   (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Under my normal user key works fine. Is it possible somehow specify `know_hosts` file from existing system user?

Answer (score 0):

The line reading:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ...'
```

is *intended* to provide an ssh key and several ssh options to the `ssh` command when Git—or more specifically, `git fetch`—uses `ssh` to call up another Git at an ssh-based URL.

This line is defective (or another line is missing), because as written, it sets the variable *without also exporting it into the environment for `git fetch`*.  If the variable already exists in the environment, this particular defect is not a problem, since already-exported variables continue to be exported; but, if as is the more typical case, the variable *does not* exist yet, this just creates the variable locally.

There are two different ways to fix it: either put the variable-setting in front of the command itself, all on one logical line, as in:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh ...' git fetch
```

Or, add an `export` command, either on the line that sets the variable, or shortly afterward:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='...'
```

or:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='...'
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND
```

Note that setting the variable on the same line as the command means to set it in the environment of that particular command, but not any longer than that.  Setting it with an explicit `export` means to set it now and keep it set that way until it is changed, or the shell exits, whichever occurs first:

```
$ USER=hello sh -c 'echo $USER'
hello
$ echo $USER
torek
$ export USER=hello
$ sh -c 'echo $USER'
hello
$ echo $USER
hello
```